# Как вернуть аплет управления звуком в трей на Kubuntu 22.10

Tags: ubuntu, kubuntu

После ребута на Kubuntu 22.10 пропал звук (при клике на аплет в трее надпись "Устройства не обнаружены"). Попробовал включить PulseAudio (Ubuntu 22.10 перешел на PipeWire по умолчанию) - с PulseAudio заработало. Но из трея пропал аплет управления звуком. Поставил какой-то аплет для PulseAudio из Discovery, но не впечатлило (не было банальной регулировки громкости).

Короче, решил снова завести PipeWire. Погуглил, доставил какие-то пакеты по первым встречным гайдам. Перезапустился. Звук появился. Но (!) в трее нет никакого аплета управления звуком (громкость/микрофон и тп). В Discovery (центр приложений) никаких аплетов для PipeWire не нашел. В настройках панели - тоже.

Вопрос прозаичный: как поставить в трей Kubuntu аплет управления звуком (как вернуть тот, который был из коробки)? :)